# ActiveAdmin list of registered pages and resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

In using `ActiveAdmin.register_page` and `ActiveAdmin.register`. How do I get a list of registered pages and resources?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using the default namespace of `:admin`, you can do the following for ActiveAdmin 0.6.1+.

```rb
resource_collection = ActiveAdmin.application.namespaces[:admin].resources

resources = resource_collection.select { |resource| resource.respond_to? :resource_class }
pages     = resource_collection.reject { |resource| resource.respond_to? :resource_class }

resource_classes = resources.map { |resource| resource.resource_class }
page_names       = pages.map     { |resource| resource.name }
```

The API is slightly different between `ActiveAdmin::Resource` and `ActiveAdmin::Page`, which is why pages and resources are extracted separately. All the resources in the namespace are in its [ResourceCollection](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/0f663e3ad728e1791be138d42e35f9f52c93d93b/lib/active_admin/resource_collection.rb).