# ActiveAdmin Show current menu structure in page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, menu, activeadmin

I got resource and pages structure with this code

```
resource_collection = ActiveAdmin.application.namespaces[:admin].resources
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19549627/activeadmin-list-of-registered-pages-and-resources)

Resource has a hash menu_item_options with id, label, url, if, parent.

I tried in rails console

```
resource_collection.first.menu_item_options[:parent]
```

and it is filled, but inside my page it is blank.

How I can get ActiveAdmin menu structure in ActiveAdmin page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default menu is available via

```
ActiveAdmin.application.namespaces[:admin].fetch_menu(:default)
```

Items are displayed if item.should_display evaluates to true. By default for a resource item this is based on whether the current user is authorized to read the resource, but it can be overridden with the item if: option. If no menu items are displayed most likely it is an authorization issue.